# $_SESSION not working after login?

Tags: php

Setting the session at login:

```
<?php

require 'lib/password.php';

include_once '../inc/dbconPDO.inc.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['user']) != "") {
    header("Location: /control/home");
}
if (isset($_POST['btn-login'])) {
    $email = strtolower($_POST['email']);
    $upass = $_POST['pass'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=:email";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $stmt->execute();

    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

    $pass = $row['password'];

    if (password_verify($upass, $pass)) {

        $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
        header("Location: /control/home");

    } else { ?>
        <script>alert("Gegevens incorrect!"); </script>
        <?php
    }

}
?>
```

Home.php:

```
<?php 
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['user']) == "") {
    header("Location: /");
}
?>
// Rest of the page below.
```

It should let me pass to the home.php page because it should've set a session at login.

Currently, whenever I go to the home.php page, I get redirected back to the homepage, meaning that the session is not active.

Could anyone tell me why this is happening?

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: include `session_start();` in the login file too.

Comment: Why would you do: `<script>alert("Gegevens incorrect!"); </script>` when you can just echo it so you can add html / css to it. If someone has turned of js the user will never get the error.

Comment: sidenote: best to add `exit;` after each header, otherwise your code may want to continue to execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `session_start();` on every page, not just the home page, and you must do it before sending any other output. Generally, it should be the very first thing in your code to avoid any problems. If you *don't* call it on every page, then `$_SESSION` will not be populated on pages that don't call `session_start()`.

Also, `isset()` returns a boolean value (`true` or `false`). You should not be comparing it to a string. Probably, you want something more like this:

```
if (!array_key_exists('user', $_SESSION) || $_SESSION['user'] === "")
{
     header("Location: /");
     exit; // stops it from further execution of code below
}
```

Plus, it's always best to add `exit;` after each header, otherwise your code may want to continue to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have initialized session in your script ? (@session_start())
And you have a mistake here :

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
 header("Location: /control/home");
}
```

Should be

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['user']))
{
 header("Location: /control/home");
}
```

Comment: also `empty` checks if the it `isset` so `empty` always best solution

Comment: while your suggestion is correct, it does nothing to solve the OP's question.

Comment: This does not answer the question